# When reload/refresh empty/delete/unset all Jinja2 variables

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a hidden input which value is going to be the variable passed from the flask view. I want to delete the value of micro when the page is reloaded.

Every time I reload the page the micro is still set.

```html
<input type="hidden" id="hide-error" value="{{micro}}">
```